# Hashmap, ArrayList... how to get the ArrayList to sum all entries together?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Apologies if this is simple, I'm relatively new to programming and thanks in advance to any help. Okay so as briefly mentioned in the title, I've created a HashMap with an ArrayList inside. At the moment I am able to retrieve an entry within the ArrayList using .getValue

I want to be able to retrieve ALL entries made via the GUI (which was the reason I created an ArrayList) but I'm finding it difficult to achieve this. So for example, if a user entered 50, 45, 40... right now it would just return 40 (the last entered number). I want to be able to retrieve all 3 numbers.

Any suggestions?

Here is my code/hashmap:

```
 public class arrayList {

 HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();


public arrayList() {}



 public void addEntryMN( String mod, Integer number ) {

ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();
num.add(number);

myMap.put(mod, num);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly for readability. If you have indented code in your environment, you can copy-paste it into the editor, then select the code, and click the `[{ }]` button at the top.

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question appears to be poorly worded.
I will assume that you want to store all values for a given key.

Answer: Get the array value from the map before adding a value.

```
ArrayList<Integer> numberList = myMap.get(mod);

if (numberList == null)
{
    numberList = new LinkedList<>();
}

num.add(number);

myMap.put(mod, num);
```

In general, prefer linkedList over arraylist it has less overhead when growing and has the same performance when iterating over the list.

Comment: Thank you for your time this is the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to go with Java 8's stream:

```
int sum = list.stream().reduce(0, (val1, val2) -> val1 + val2);
```

Explanation: summing the values in the collection is a 'reduce' operation - you're reducing multiple values to a single value - in this case by adding them. 0 (zero) is the 'identity', that is the value from which you start adding, and the funky lambda (val1, val2) -> val1 + val2, tells what should be done with the ints in the collection: in this case you want to addem them.

Assuming the values in the list are: `1, 2, 2, 4` the stream can be immagined to work as follows:

```
- 0 + 1 = 1
- 1 + 2 = 3
- 3 + 2 = 5
- 5 + 4 = 9
```

Comment: I don't use Java 8 and don't know how to.